# Push on two iterators at the same time

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, iterator

I have an usual For/each iterator:

```
For Each food In foods
   ' Iterate over food
Next
```

In addition to `foods`, suppose I have another list `beverages`. Elements in each list have an `Import` field. I would to sum the i-th `Import` of a `beverage` element, with the i-th element of a `food` element, and put the result in a new list (each list is different from the others). Something like:

```
checkout.Add(beverage.Import + food.Import)
```

I could take note of number of iterations and get the related beverage element and then sum it, but I think this is pretty unelegant. I would like to iterate over two collections at the same time, a sort of

```
For Each food In foods And beverage In beverages
    checkout.Add(beverage.Import + food.Import)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for Linq's [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var beverages = ...;
var foods = ...;

var sumSequence = foods.Zip(beverages, (food, beverage) => beverage.Import + food.Import);
foreach (var importSum in sumSequence)
{
    checkout.Add(importSum);
}
```

Apologizes for c# code.

Here is a example in VB.NET

```
Dim beverages () As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4}
Dim foods() As String = {"one", "two", "three"}
Dim numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(beverages, Function(food, beverage) beverage.Import & " " & food.Import)

For Each item In numbersAndWords
    Console.WriteLine(item)
Next 

' This code produces the following output: 

' 1 one 
' 2 two 
' 3 three
```

Comment: @SSpoke: Thanks for Vb.net sample

Comment: No problem found it from your microsoft link :P